# Shopware6 order state transition throws 500 status code error

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

we have a technical issue with the API that performs the order state transition on our Shopware6 DemoStore.

Whenever we call the order state transition API, on the first attempt we get a 500 error, on the second we get 200.
Even if we get 500 status code in the response, we see on the admin panel that the order status gets updated.
We tried different integrations, even with Admin permissions, but we still get the same error.

I'll leave here an example request:

First attempt (500 error, but order status still gets updated):

```
POST /api/_action/order/1fa508dcfbcf4fa2ae17a880708d5c4b/state/process

{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "0",
            "status": "500",
            "title": "Internal Server Error",
            "detail": "Could not find order context with referenced_order_id \"1fa508dcfbcf4fa2ae17a880708d5c4b\"."
        }
    ]
}
```

Second attempt (200 ok):

```
POST /api/_action/order/1fa508dcfbcf4fa2ae17a880708d5c4b/state/process

{
    "name": "In Bearbeitung",
    "technicalName": "in_progress",
    "stateMachineId": "829e4b7329d648e3af48c87bf3838b9b",
    "stateMachine": null,
    "fromStateMachineTransitions": null,
    "toStateMachineTransitions": null,
    "translations": null,
    "orders": null,
    "orderTransactionCaptures": null,
    "orderTransactionCaptureRefunds": null,
    "orderTransactions": null,
    "orderDeliveries": null,
    "fromStateMachineHistoryEntries": null,
    "toStateMachineHistoryEntries": null,
    "_uniqueIdentifier": "aa16871f5106458c82cc72c5aba45873",
    "versionId": null,
    "translated": {
        "name": "In Bearbeitung",
        "customFields": []
    },
    "createdAt": "2022-04-15T10:14:05.167+00:00",
    "updatedAt": null,
    "extensions": {
        "foreignKeys": {
            "apiAlias": null,
            "extensions": []
        }
    },
    "id": "aa16871f5106458c82cc72c5aba45873",
    "customFields": null
}
```

Some days ago we didn't have this problem. Could it be dued to some update that has been released recently on the DemoStore? Actual version is 6.4.15.0.

Comment: Did you change something in the system? New plugins? Could you check the error log for a more detailed error message?

Comment: Hello, I found a log that may be connected to our error. Here the stack error:

{
  "component": "Unknown component",
  "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'b2bOrderReferenceHolder')\n    at s.getOrderReferenceNumber ({{host}}/bundles/swagb2bplatform/administration/js/swag-b2b-platform.js?1673967877138657:1:78937)\n ...

Error stack is too long to be fully attached, hope it helps.
I can't find any other error logs, even if I fire new requests and they keep failing.

Comment: We recently added our app to the store in private mode (with dev secret into manifest.xml) that we are testing before releasing into the store.
The app is a simple manifest.xml that performs store registration as pointed in the documentation.
That is the only plugin/app we added.

Comment: I tried to uninstall the app to test if that was the problem, we still get the same behavior

Comment: That error seems unrelated, but it shows me you're using the B2B Suite. Your original error is triggered by the b2b suite because there is no OrderContext (an entity provided by the b2b suite). I assume that it's created on the fly while updating the order, thus the following requests are fine.
As far as I understand the code that error should be catched, but seems to bubble up in your case. Maybe it has been fixed in newer versions? You could try to update the b2b suite. The error is triggered in `Shopware\B2B\Order\Framework\OrderContextRepository::fetchOneOrderContextByReferencedOrderId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled the "B2B-Suite for Shopware" extension and now the API always answers 200 at the first call.
As suggested by Timo Helmke the problem is coming from this:

**Shopware\B2B\Order\Framework\OrderContextRepository::fetchOneOrderContextByReferencedOrderId**

The actual extension version is  4.6.5.